# For this function, is f is injective?

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, injective-module

For $f(f(x))=x$ where $f: X →X,~∀x ∈ X$. Is $f$ is injective? 
From what I can see, since the condition $f: X \to X$ is satisfied by all elements of $X$, $f(x)$ must $= x$. Also, I know if $g$ is an inverse of $f$, then $g(f(x))=x$, but should I use this property to prove injection?

Comment: Start with $f(a) = f(b)$ and apply $f$ on both sides. What happens?

Comment: So if I assume f(a)=f(b), that means a=b, right?

Comment: Of course. $f$ is obviously bijective (and its is own inverse) so in particular injective...

Comment: Would I start with assuming f(a)=f(b), hence after applying the formula given, I'd have f(f(a))=f(f(b)) which implies a=b?

Comment: @NikiM: You got the right idea. See if my answer helps to make the logical structure unambiguously clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it's not correct to "define $f(f(x))=x$". All you can say is "**If** $f : X \to X$ for some collection $X$ such that $f(f(x))=x$ for any $x \in X$, **then** ... [what you can deduce about such an $f$ goes here] ...". Also, it is false that such an $f$ must satisfy $f(x) = x$ even for one $x \in X$. I'm sure you can figure out a counter-example where $X$ has just $2$ elements.

So what do you want to prove? If you want to prove that such an $f$ is injective, you want exactly the following logical structure.

~~~

For any collection $X$ and function $f : X \to X$ such that $f(f(x)) = x$ for every $x \in X$:

For any $a,b \in X$:

If $f(a) = f(b)$ then:

$a = b$.

~~~

You should then realize that this is easy to obtain as follows:

~~~

For any collection $X$ and function $f : X \to X$ such that $f(f(x)) = x$ for every $x \in X$:

For any $a,b \in X$:

If $f(a) = f(b)$ then:

$f(f(a)) = f(f(b))$ [by substitution].

$a = b$.

~~~

Comment: I didn't understand the first part of what you said about it being false, but the rest makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: @NikiM: I was saying that your claim `From what I can see, since the condition f: X -> X is satisfied by all elements of X, f(x) must = x.` is false.

Comment: I see. But if it's false that f(x)=x then how can I use the fact that f(b)=f(a) implies a=b? Am I not using the fact that f(b)=b and f(a)=a?

Comment: @NikiM: That's why there's an additional step needed. From $f(a) = f(b)$ (they're substitutable for one another) you should agree that $f(f(a)) = f(f(b))$ by substitution. Then here's where you need the assumed property of $f$.

Comment: @NikiM: Of course, it's your discretion whether to give more intermediate details, such as $a = f(f(a)) = ...$. Got it now?

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @NikiM: You're welcome! If you're satisfied with the answer, you can accept it by clicking the check-mark.